# apollo graphql UI is not updating after refetch

Tags: reactjs, apollo

In a react login component, I'd like to refetch and update the navbar component once login is successful.

```
const loginUser = () => {
    props.mutate({
      variables: {
        input: { email, password },
      },
      refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_ME }],
    });
  };
```

I can see the login and re-fetch in network tab, and both return 200 with proper status. But the navbar still displays the old data.

Here is my navbar component.

```
export const Header = props => {
  return <div>Header {JSON.stringify(props.data)}</div>;
};

export default graphql(GET_ME)(Header);
```

And apolloClient:

```
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: createHttpLink({
    credentials: 'include',
    uri: 'http://localhost:8080/api/graphql',
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

Comment: please update if you find a solution! running into a similar issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What John said could be the solution to some people, but it wasn't mine.

For me, it is pretty typical to get a return of nothing or an error when query `getMe` if user isn't logged in.

Because of that, the next call will not reset the cache, which bugs out the entire system.

The solution to my problem was giving an `errorPolicy` of none.

```
export const isAuth = compose(
  graphql(GET_ME, {
    options: {
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
      errorPolicy: 'ignore',
    },
  })
);
```

Since I am using HOC, this is my solution.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding

```
 options: {
      awaitRefetchQueries: true
 },
```

to your props.mutate next to refetchQueries and variables.

Queries refetched using options.refetchQueries are handled asynchronously, which means by default they are not necessarily completed before the mutation has completed. Setting options.awaitRefetchQueries to true will make sure refetched queries are completed before the mutation is considered done (or resolved). options.awaitRefetchQueries is false by default.

Comment: this may have solved the problem for me, but what i did was something different by using fetchPolicy and errorPolicy

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem where the `data` from the useQuery hook was not updating after calling the `refetch` function. In my case, the cause of the problem was the onError callback. Removing this and using a useEffect hook to watch the `error` variable fixed the issue.

```
const { data, loading, refetch } = useQuery(GET_LIST, {
    variables: {
        offset: 0,
        limit: 50,
    },
    onError: () => {
       // handle error here
    },
})
```

Change to:

```
const { data, loading, refetch, error } = useQuery(GET_LIST, {
    variables: {
        offset: 0,
        limit: 50,
    },
})

useEffect(() => {
    if(error){
        // handle error here
    }
}, [error])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at GitHub issues about this, it appears there may be a bit of a glitch in `refetch`. In my case it put the latest data in the cache, but did not trigger a React refresh.

Here's how I solved it:

```
const loading = useRef(false);
const dataToDisplay = useRef([]]);
const [toggleRefresh, setToggleRefresh] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    loading.current = true;
    client.query({
        query: MY_QUERY,
        variables: {"myVar": myVar},
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        skip: loading.current
    }).then((result) => {
        loading.current = false;
        dataToDisplay.current = result.data.dataToDisplay;
        setToggleRefresh(!toggleRefresh); //cheesy but it seems to work
    });
}, [varThatTriggersRefetchWhenChanged]);
```

You might say, "But that doesn't make sense. `skip` is set to `loading.current`, and `loading.current` has to be true at that point."

Based on other SO posts, I *think* the new value for a useRef may not be there until the next render.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the useQuery hook where the data wasn't updating even after using the refetch function.

The issue was the skip property:

```
  const {
    data: users,
    loading: usersLoading,
    refetch: getUsersByOrgId,
  } = useUsersByOrgIdQuery({
    variables: {
      orgId: props.orgId,
    },
    // --> skip: props.orgId,
  });
```

After commenting the `skip` the `data` was updated.